# Math mode in tables

Tags: tables, math-mode

I am trying to write notations like degree, micro etc in a table with math mode on. To form the table, i am using -

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
```

But in my table when i type

```
$^\circ$
```

it gives out the same `($^\circ$)` as a result, where its supposed to give me a degree notation. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: To type units, I suggest using `siunitx` which also offers a tabular with `S` column. You have to use `\degreeCelsius` there.

Answer (score 10):

The `array` environment is in math mode, so you need to use `{}^\circ`.  In `tabular` you need to use `${}^\circ$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        ${}^\circ$
    \end{tabular}

    $\begin{array}{c}
        {}^\circ
    \end{array}$
\end{document}
```